# How to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{k!} }\sim \frac{n}{\ln n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Recently I have met this asymptotic estimation:
prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{k!} }\sim \frac{n}{\ln n}$，$n\to \infty$.

Here is the way I think:

According to area principle，
\begin{align*}
 \Bigg|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{k!} }-\int_1^n\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\Gamma(x+1)}}d x\Bigg|\leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\Gamma(n+1)}}
\end{align*}
Thus we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\ln n}{n}\Bigg|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{k!} }-\int_1^n\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\Gamma(x+1)}}d x\Bigg|\leqslant \frac{\ln n}{n}\frac1{\sqrt[n]{\Gamma(n+1)}}\sim \frac{\ln n}{n}\cdot \frac1{\sqrt[n]{2\pi n}} \frac{e}{n}\to 0,~~n\to \infty
\end{align*}
To this end we only need to show
\begin{align*}
\int_1^n\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\Gamma(x+1)}}d x\sim \frac{n}{\ln n}
\end{align*}
 But my train of thought is stuck here.Can you give me any help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe you can use the stirling approximation again?

Comment: My computer shows that $\frac{\ln n}{n}\sum(sth)\to0\neq1$. Where did you find the result?

Comment: Is your question answered or is something still unclear? ;)

Answer (score 9):

Using the stirling formula and partial integration we get:

$\displaystyle\frac{\ln n}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!^{1/n}} \sim \frac{\ln n}{n}\int\limits_1^n\frac{dx}{\Gamma(1+x)^{1/n}} = (\ln n)\int\limits_{1/n}^1\frac{dx}{\Gamma(1+nx)^{1/n}}
\sim  (\ln n)\int\limits_{1/n}^1\frac{dx}{(nx/e)^x}$

$\displaystyle = \left(\frac{\ln n}{(x/e)^x}\frac{n^{-x}}{-\ln n}\right)\bigg|_{1/n}^1 + \int\limits_{1/n}^1\frac{\ln \frac{1}{x}}{(nx/e)^x}dx \enspace$ with 
$\enspace\displaystyle \left(\frac{\ln n}{(x/e)^x}\frac{n^{-x}}{-\ln n}\right)\bigg|_{1/n}^1 \sim 1$

$\displaystyle 0< \int\limits_{1/n}^1\frac{\ln \frac{1}{x}}{(nx/e)^x}dx < e\int\limits_0^1\frac{\ln \frac{1}{x}}{n^x}dx =\frac{e}{\ln n}\left(\gamma+\ln\ln n+\int\limits_{\ln n}^\infty\frac{dt}{te^t}\right)\sim\frac{e\ln\ln n}{\ln n}\sim 0$

with the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\,\gamma\,$

It follows $\enspace\displaystyle\frac{\ln n}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!^{1/n}} \sim 1\enspace$ and therefore the claim.

*Note:*

$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^1\frac{\ln \frac{1}{x}}{e^{ax}}dx=\frac{\ln a + \gamma + \Gamma(0,a)}{a}\sim \frac{\ln a}{a}\enspace$ with the incomplete Gamma function $\,\Gamma(.,.)$

Comment: How can you get 0 after partial integration?I have tried,the part is$n\int_{\frac1n}^1\frac{n^{-x}}{-\ln n}\cdot \Big(\frac{e}{x}\Big)^x\ln \frac{1}{x}dx$,and since $1 \leqslant \Big(\frac{e}{x}\Big)^x \leqslant e$,so if that part tend to 0,we must have $\int_{\frac1n}^1\frac{n}{\ln n} n^{-x}\ln \frac{1}{x}dx\to 0$,$n\to \infty$,but it's impossible ,for in fact we can see $\int_{\frac1n}^1\frac{n}{\ln n} n^{-x}\ln \frac{1}{x}dx\to +\infty$!

Comment: @mbfkk : In my first version of my answer I simply forgot $n$ . Hope it's better now. :) I'm sorry about the inconvenience and misunderstandings. I've done the calculation of the last integral of my answer with the help of WolframAlpha. It was necessary to show, that the divergence of the last integral of your comment above is irrelevant regarding $n/\ln n$ .

Comment: Nice done!Thanks!

Comment: @mbfkk: You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 7):

For any $x>0$, $$c_1\,x^{x+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-x}\leq \Gamma(x+1)\leq c_2\,x^{x+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-x}$$ for some $c_1,c_2>0$ (see for example [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)). Therefore, $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{c_2}}\int_1^nx^{-x/n}x^{-\frac{1}{2n}}e^{x/n}\,dx\leq \int_1^n\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\Gamma(x+1)}}\,dx\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{c_1}}\int_1^nx^{-x/n}x^{-\frac{1}{2n}}e^{x/n}\,dx.$$ Next, note that $$n^{-\frac{1}{2n}}\int_1^nx^{-x/n}e^{x/n}\,dx\leq\int_1^nx^{-x/n}x^{-\frac{1}{2n}}e^{x/n}\,dx\leq \int_1^nx^{-x/n}e^{x/n}\,dx,$$ so it suffices to find the asymptotics of the last integral.

Comment: ... which can be done through Laplace method. Nice approach, (+1).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm still puzzled at how to get the asymptotics of $\int_1^nx^{-x/n}e^{x/n}\,dx$.Can you give any clearer hint?

Answer (score 3):

The terms $\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{k!}}$, for $k\in[1,n]$, are roughly of the same size, hence the upper bound provided by Holder's inequality
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{k!}}\leq \sqrt[n]{n^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}}\leq \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n/e}}$$
is expected to be close to the asymptotic behaviour of the RHS.
 It can be improved via (I am going to outline the case $n=4$ for simplicity)
$$\sum_{k=1}^{4}\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{k!}}\leq \sqrt[4]{\left(\tfrac{1}{1}+\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{3}+\tfrac{1}{4}\right)\left(\tfrac{1}{1}+\tfrac{1}{1}+\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{3}\right)\left(\tfrac{1}{1}+\tfrac{1}{1}+\tfrac{1}{1}+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\left(\tfrac{1}{1}+\tfrac{1}{1}+\tfrac{1}{1}+\tfrac{1}{1}\right)}$$
leading to
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{k!}}\leq \sqrt[n]{\prod_{h=0}^{n-1}\left(h+H_{n-h}\right)}.\tag{U}$$
On the other hand Holder's inequality can be used also for producing a lower bound:

$$ \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{k!}}\right)^n \geq \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n+1]{k!}}\right)^{n+1}$$
$$ \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n+1]{k!}}\right)^{n+1} \geq \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n+2]{k!}}\right)^{n+2}$$

lead to
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{k!}}\geq \frac{1}{n^{1/n}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n+1]{k!}}\right)^{\frac{n+1}{n}}\geq \frac{1}{n^{2/n}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n+2]{k!}}\right)^{\frac{n+2}{n}}\geq\ldots\geq\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt[2n]{k!}}\right)^2,$$

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{k!}}\geq\frac{1}{n^n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n^2]{k!}}\right)^{n+1}\tag{L}$$
and for any $k\in[1,n]$ the distance between $\sqrt[2n]{k!}$ and $1$ is $O\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)$ by Stirling's approximation. 
The asymptotic behaviour of your sum should now follow by comparing the accurate upper bound $(U)$ and the accurate lower bound $(L)$.